# react getting div clientWidth is returning null in component didUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I have a react component with an image inside it. I need the image dimentions (not the window dimentions) for some other codes that I do with the image element. when I simply render the component everything is ok but when I refresh the webpage this.imgEl.clientWidth will be undefined does anyone have a solution for that ?

to be precise in this code chunk below when I refresh the page dimentions are undefined so size will remain 0 and componentdidupdate will run infinitely

my component code is like this:

```
class myComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSizeChange = this.handleSizeChange.bind(this);
    }
 state = {
        size: {x: 0, y: 0}
}

 componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleSizeChange)
//then fetch data and a state change
}

 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        if (this.state.size.x === 0 || this.state.size.y === 0) {
            this.handleSizeChange()
        }
    }

 componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleSizeChange);
    }

handleSizeChange() {
     
        this.setState({size: {x: this.imgEl.clientWidth, y: this.imgEl.clientHeight}});
    }



    render() {
        return (
                <Box m={1} style={{zIndex: 1,minHeight:"97vh"}}>
                            <img ref={(imgEl) => {
                                this.imgEl = imgEl
                            }} src={im} onClick={this.onClick}
                                 style={{maxHeight: "97vh", maxWidth: "90vw"}}/>
                </Box>
)}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the image has not loaded yet. You can listen for the `load` event on the image - after its been fully loaded, that is when you access its dimensions.

```
const imgEl = new Image();
imgEl.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  // this.imgEl.clientWidth should now return correct width
})
imgEl.src = someImage;
```